# what is the use of getStacktrace(),setStackTrace()?I am unable to understand what is the need of this function?

Tags: java, exception

I am unable to understand this code.. I am well aware about the syntax but why is `getStackTrace()` and `setStackTrace()` is used? I mean I want to know what is its implementation in real world scenario? i.e., what is the desired output of this code?

```
package stackTrace;

class a {
    public void fun() {
        try {
            findexception();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            StackTraceElement[] x = e.getStackTrace();
            System.err.println(x[1].toString());

        }
    }

    public void findexception() throws Exception {
        // int i=0;
        Exception ex = new Exception();
        StackTraceElement[] y = new StackTraceElement[2];

        y[0] = new StackTraceElement("class0", "method0", "type0", 0);
        y[1] = new StackTraceElement("class1", "method1", "type1", 1);

        ex.setStackTrace(y);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;

    }
}

public class stackTrace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a obj = new a();
        obj.fun();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The main Idea of that is to customize the stack trace regarding your use cases(Custom error handling with some extra information needed in the stacktrace e.g.) because:**

The **setStackTrace (StackTraceElement[] stackTrace)** method of Throwable class is used to Set the stack trace elements to this throwable object and this stack trace will be returned by **getStackTrace()** and printed by **printStackTrace()** and related methods. 
   This method allows the user to override the default stack trace that is either generated by **fillInStackTrace()** when a throwable is constructed or deserialized when a throwable is read from a serialization stream.

Comment: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072391/the-surprisingly-simple-stacktraceelement.html